# C# send data to remote server

Tags: c#, connection

I have a client and server in C# and currently they are only able to communicate under a local network. How do I create a remote connection?

Currently I have started looking at web services and getting to know what it can do.

I have also heard several advice such as using free hosting cloud/web server.

Is there any other methods to achieve my goal?

Can anybody guide me to the correct path?

Comment: Please rephrase your question after reading [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. 
But what you're looking for is called IPC, or just look here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

In my opinion, using RESTful services should get you what you need.

I am sorry I cant provide you with more help , but your question can have many answers.

Hope I was some help.  =)

Comment: Thanks! Definitely will go look up on it! @TheNoob